# Org Mode - Targeted Expansion of Headings

Tags: org-mode

In org mode with the headings collapsed you can go to each one and press TAB to expand it.

Is there an easy way to not have to navigate to headings by using the arrow keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious response is that you can bound `org-next-visible-heading` and `org-previous-visible-heading` with whatever key you like, but arrow keys are busy ones in the org keymap.

Supossing that you want to completely override up and down keys when org-mode is your major mode, this, in your init file, will do it.

```lisp
(define-key org-mode-keymap (kbd "<down>") 'org-next-visible-heading)
(define-key org-mode-keymap (kbd "<up>")   'org-previous-visible-heading)
```

Comment: Thank you, can you provide the command for the binding to a random key and I will place my preference in it?

Comment: @Adam I've edited the response with your request.

Answer (score 0):

Use `C-c C-j` (org-goto) for that functionality.